# Does this sentence with ことになる make sense?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I am trying to check my understanding about ことになる, so I came up with a sentence:

> 日本語を勉強することが好きなことになった

The meaning I intended is "I came to enjoy studying japanese".

Does the sentence mean this ? And is it grammatically correct ?

Comment: It looked like こ**の**になる was a typo, so I changed it to match the example (こ**と**になる).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically correct, but it means "Studying Japanese became my favourite thing (to do)".

If you want to say "I came to enjoy studying Japanese", you can leave out the 〜なこと and say

> 日本語を勉強することが好きになってきた。

Comment: I understand the reason for the meaning "became my favourite thing to do". But wouldn´t the phrase be ambiguous, rather than have only one possible meaning ? Also, Tae Kim says that になる can only be used with a verb-sentence if one uses こと

Comment: Sorry, sent the comment by mistake before finishing it: @istrasci, Tae Kim guide says になる　can be used with verbs only if you use こと　or よう, like I tried to do... Am I understanding something wrong about this ?

Comment: ???  You did not use the form になる with a verb.  You used it with 好き.

Comment: Hmm... what if the sentence was 日本語を勉強することが好きことになった ?

Comment: That is your original sentence (minus the missing な after 好き), but this also isn't using ～になる with a verb; it boils down to 好きなことになる.  I don't think I understand what you're trying to ask concerning ～になる with verbs.  Maybe you should make a new topic.

Comment: @istraci, I am not sure if I should make a new topic... I thought that I could treat the sentence "日本語を勉強することが好き" as a whole, like "日本語を勉強することが好き" = x , then say "xことになる". This seems to be the logic when "x" is a verb sentence, but in this case "x" has no verb, so I don´t know whether it´s right or not.